# Should I use sonkeigo if I meet a celebrity?

Tags: politeness

Yesterday I met a very famous Japanese person. I panicked and asked him, 「写真をとってもよろしいでしょうか」

Was this correct? Or was this too polite and kind of strange?

Comment: Panicking when you meet them is a well-accepted form of respect :)

Comment: FWIW, that sentence includes no 尊敬語 (by its strict linguistic definition). It’s just further along the 丁寧語 gradient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you met him privately, yes that was correct. 写真撮ってもいいですか is usually acceptable (especially if you are young), but 写真を撮ってもよろしいでしょうか is never overly polite nor strange.